# How to overcome Mixed Content error without using proxy server if not How to remove ssl certificate from website hosted in vercel

Tags: javascript, ssl, web, next.js, vercel

I made a website using `NextJs` that takes [list of websites](https://sourav9063.github.io/ftp-nextron/api/db.json) (that includes http:// and https:// websites) and checks whether the client can access the websites or not from client's network.

Here is the main [website](https://search-ftp.vercel.app/) and [source code](https://github.com/Sourav9063/search-ftp).

I hosted the website using [vercel](https://vercel.com/). Which provided me with an ssl certified website. But now I cannot fetch the `http://*` websites.
Getting this error:

```
Mixed Content: The page at '<URL>' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure resource '<URL>'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

[image]

Here is the check function:

```
export const getWorkingNotSureFromList = async ({
  setWorking,
  setNotSure,
  listOFLinks,
}) => {
  console.log("checking");
  listOFLinks.forEach(async (link) => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch(link, { mode: "no-cors" });

      if (response.ok) {
        console.log(link);
        setWorking((state) => {
          return [...state, { link: link, message: "Working" }];
        });
      } else {
        setWorking((state) => {
          return [...state, { link: link, message: "Working" }];
        });
      }
    } catch (e) {
      setNotSure((state) => {
        return [...state, { link: link, message: "Not Sure" }];
      });
    }
  });
};
```

**Note**
I cannot use a proxy server to overcome this error. Because the check has to be done in the client's ISP.

**Things I need help with**

- Is there any other way just to check whether the client has access to a website using JS in the browser overcoming CORS and Content Security Policy issues?Or,
- Can I use `window.open()` and check if the url (not same origin) connects or not from my website?Or,
- How to access `http://*` from `https://*`.Or,
- How can I allow insecure content for my website using js or meta tag?Or,
- If there is no other way, How to remove ssl certificate provided by vercel.Or,
- Is there any free hosting provider that hosts NextJs or static site that doesn't provide ssl certificate?(I know the security issue but my website doesn't require any.)

**Thanks for taking the time to read it.**